# Failure to send email using one page submission

Tags: php, html, email

am trying to use PHP to send mails from a form using one page submission but i seem to be missing something since no mail is sent on submission neither does it throw up an error (which is rather weird). Below is the PHP and HTML form codes which are on the same file
PHP Script

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: risingventures.com.ng';
    $to = 'inquiry@risingventures.com.ng';
    $subject = 'New message from contact form';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: from@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: reply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch with you soon</div>';
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry! There was an error submitting your message. Please try again</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

HTML code

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
            <legend>Contact Us</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <label>Name *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Please type your Firstname followed by your Lastname">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Please type in your email address *">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Please type in your phone number">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <label>Message *</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                    <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: your `$from` is not a valid header

Comment: @Dagon I have edited the php code, adding headers but still failed to send mail. Any comment on the new code?

Comment: @luweiqi I have included headers to my php script now and still unable to send mail. Looking at my code now, do you still feel it's a duplicate? I just can't place it why the sending fails

Comment: @Mena It might actually due to your hosting

Comment: @luweiqi so does the code look right?

Comment: Fixed the problem by including the name="submit" attribute in the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

after I have checked the form tag of your html, I observed the following

1. The enctype attribute that specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server was absent, the enctype attribute is required if method="post". this can be either multipart/form-data,text/plain, or application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. if this does not fix it remove the role = form and try again